# Constructing images using HTMl markup

Tags: html

Einstein wrote: `<var>E</var> = <var>mc</var><sup>2</sup>`

```
!DOCTYPE HTML

<HTML>

<Head> 

      <Title>fci<\title>

<\head> 

<Body>

<table>

 <tr>

  <th>Name</th>

  <th>Favorite Color</th>

 </tr>

 <tr>

  <td>Bob</td>

  <td>Yellow</td>

 </tr>

 <tr>

  <td>Michelle</td>

  <td>Purple</td>


 </tr>

</table>

<\body>

<\html>
```

Comment: Do you actually have a question?

Answer (score 0):

Actually your question is not delivered properly, anyhow there's markup errors in your code. Your code should be as follows,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>fci</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Favorite Color</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bob</td>
        <td>Yellow</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Michelle</td>
        <td>Purple</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

To close a HTML tag you should use forward slash '/' 
example: `<h1></h1>`